# not able to successfully slice a json file with jq

Tags: json, slice, jq

I try to slice the json file but it's giving me the error:

**jq: error (at result2.json:0): Cannot index array with string "url"**

I am trying to parse the following json file

[code ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z54AJ.png)

I want to access six reference links from this list. I tried using the following code but it's giving me an error.

**jq -r .result.CVE_Items[].cve.references.reference_data[0:5].url result2.json**

I am fairly new to json parsing so i am having a tough time overcoming these issues :(

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please follow the [mcve] guidelines. In particular, in your case, a small sample of the input JSON should be provided as part of the question. Providing a link to an image of incomplete JSON is seldom useful and never a satisfactory substitute.

Comment: Go it! I'll keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.reference_data[0:5]` produces a slice, i.e. an array, so in your query, you would need to itemize it, e.g. by appending []:

```
.reference_data[0:5][]
```

Comment: Thanks! I kind of feel dumb asking such questions but thanks for bearing with me!